# WPF: ComboBox DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

XAML:

```
 <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="UserSelectComboBox" Margin="68.497,31.75,0,48.213" 
  Background=   {DynamicResource TextBoxBackground}" Height="{DynamicResource 
  TextBoxHeight}" FontSize="{DynamicResource TextFontSize}" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="149.333" Text="{Binding  
  SelectedItemValue, ElementName=UserSelectComboBox, Mode=OneWay}">
  <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="{Binding UImages, Converter=   {StaticResource 
              byteToImageConverter}}" Width="40" Height="40"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding UId}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

I am using DevExpress ComboBox. When I select any item in the ComboBox then its text shows *Procesta.CvServer.Class.Propertys.UserTeamView* which is my binding source's name.

[image]

I want to show only UId.

Comment: In DevExpress ComboBox there is no Text Search Property. Which i looking for. Thank`s all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding `Text` to `SelectedItemValue`. Try binding to `SelectedItemValue.UId` instead.